# Compare data from two same tables (different dates)in access and flag the differences

Tags: excel, ms-access

I need a query or a way to compare two same tables in ACCESS(different dates). Name of the tables are NEW and OLD. The table has 4 Columns: ID, cellname, Status, Parameter1
I need to compare status and parameter1 (columns) for each cellname from both the tables and flag the values that do not match

## NEW

```
ID  cellname    Status  Parameter1
1   MO5055  Not Reserved    25
2   MO5056  Not Reserved    25
3   MO5057  Not Reserved    25
4   MO5058  Not Reserved    25
```

## OLD

```
ID  cellname    Status  Parameter1
1   MO5055  Not Reserved    25
2   MO5056  Reserved        25
3   MO5057  Not Reserved    15
4   MO5058  Reserved        15
```

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you actually ask...

Comment: Hi Please let me know if you are able to understand my question after the changes

Comment: Is this in Access or Excel, if in Access, You'd need a join, like `select q.cellname from (select new.cellname,new.status as NEWSTA,old.status as OLDSTA from new inner join old on old.cellname=new.cellname) as q where q.OLDSTA<>q.NEWSTA`  if in excel, vlookup the new using the old cellname

Comment: Thanks Nathan_Sav.. It worked but i want this to compare 255 columns

Comment: Sorry, but this still makes little sense. You claim your tables have 4 columns, but in the comment you mention comparing 255 columns... Also, what do you actually mean by "flag the values"? Why doesn't a simple query using "nor equals" and "or" operators solve your task, which you undoubtedly tried? And why don't you post your current attempts to shed light on where you are actually heading?